# power series and sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\{ $a_n$ : n\geq 1\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that radius of convergence of the power series : P(t) = $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n $ satisfies $R > 0$.Then $ a_n \rightarrow 0$???

What i was able to do is :

To find R, I applied root test of convergence:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n t^n|^{1/n} < 1 $$

on further solving, we will get:

$$  |t| < [1/{\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}}] $$

therefore we get the value of R as :

$$\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}} [1]$$

Now, $R>0$ (given)

Thus, by [1]

$$\frac{1}{(\lim_{n\to\infty}) |a_n|^{1/n}}> 0$$

or we can also write it as :

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}  > 0 $$

or

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| > 0 $$

on removing the modulus sign,this will give us:

$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n > 0$    or  $ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n  < 0 $

As a result we see that $a_n$ never converges to $0$.it either converges to some number greater than $0$ or less than $0$.

Now,this is what i have been able to do.But i am not sure if i am right on this one.Can anyone let me know if i am right and if i am wrong somewhere,plz do tell where i have made mistake.

One more question..the power series can start at any number "n" right?? i know this fact.just wanted to confirm.

Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: Your initial claim isn't true. The power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1\cdot t^n$ has radius of convergence $1$, e.g..

Comment: On the other hand, your claim is true if $R>1$ (take $t=1$).

Comment: @NasuSama ... u did wrong edit..lemme correct it out..

Comment: @DavidMitra..its right R would be 1 when $ a_n $ is 1.no doubt.i m sorry i am not able to get which claim  you are talking about.can you plz be more specific..i simply applied root convergence test and followed the simple procedure...can u point out my mistake plz ..thnks :)

Comment: The claim that if the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n t^n$ has positive radius of convergence, then $a_n\rightarrow0$. This is false.

Comment: @sunnyverma If the radius of the series $R>1$ then necessary $a_n\to0$ and if $R\leq1$ then $(a_n)$ may not converge to $0$.

Comment: @SBR... got it...thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** what about the power series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n$$

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence of $\sum_n n^{100000000000000}x^n$ is $1$, so $(a_n)$ doesn't converge necessarily to $0$.